# Lower-bounds of a given problem

Tags: complexity-theory, lower-bounds

I have the following problem:

> You have n objects that have identical weight except for one that is a
>   bit heavier than the others. You have a balance scale. You can place
>   objects on each side of the scale and see which collection is heavier.
>
> Goal is to find the heavier object, with the minimum number of weigh.

I know the best algorithm that can solve this problem. Here is the pseudocode:

```
function findDiffWeight(L[1:n]){

   if(L.size == 1) return L[1]

   int x = sum(L[1 : n/2])
   int y = sum(L[n/2+1 : n])

   if(x>y)  call findDiffWeight(L[1 : n/2])
   if(y>x)  call findDiffWeight(L[n/2+1 : n])
}
```

But I am struggling with finding the lower bound for this problem. I don't think that there can be a better algorithm that can solve this in less than `logn` operations.

However how to prove it?
Could you give me some idea about finding lower bound for this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that sorting has a $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound? A similar principle applies here.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden This will only give $\log_3 n$ rather than $\log_2 n$, since we could also have equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm, which requires $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ weighings, is in fact not optimal. [This paper](http://math.uni.lodz.pl/~andkom/Marcel/Kule-en.pdf) proposes an algorithm which uses $\lceil \log_3 n \rceil$ weighings, which is optimal by the argument outlined by Tom van der Zanden. Let's assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of 3, leaving the general case as an exercise. Suppose we are given $3^k$ objects, which we divide into three groups $X,Y,Z$ of size $3^{k-1}$. We weight $X$ against $Y$. If $X > Y$, we recurse with $X$; if $Y > X$, we recurse with $Y$; if $X = Y$, we recurse with $Z$. After $k$ such steps, we will have zeroed in on a single object.

For the lower bound, suppose that we only do $k$ weighings. There are $3^k$ possible outcomes of this weighings – each one can be either "left side heavier", "right side heavier", or "both have the same weight" – and each of them causes the algorithm to output a definite answer. Since any of the $n$ objects could be the heavier one, we must have $3^k \geq n$. This argument will make more sense after you review the $\Omega(n\log n)$ comparison lower bound for sorting.